# GCM messages not sent in parallel, chat users have to wait for long time

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android chat application that uses XMPP server (I make it) <===> GCM for messaging.

all the message (upstream and downstream) are via GCM :

[Device]--->GCM--->[xmpp] and [xmpp]-->GCM--->[device]

When the server sends many messages(i.e broadcast) to the GCM at same time, other messages don't arrive from devices to the server (GCM is busy)until the xmpp server send all it's messages to the GCM, then It can receive new messages from the user via GCM.
here is to the send function:

```
  public void send(String jsonRequest) {
        Packet request = new GcmPacketExtension(jsonRequest).toPacket();
        connection.sendPacket(request);
    }
```

**Update:**

```
 connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "[{0}]  {1}", new Object[]{Tools.getFormatedTime(), packet.toXML()});
            //Message incomingMessage = (Message) packet;

            GcmPacketExtension gcmPacket
                    = (GcmPacketExtension) ((Message) packet).getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE);
            String json = gcmPacket.getJson();
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, Object> jsonMap
                        = (Map<String, Object>) parseWithException(json);




 handleMessage(jsonMap);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing JSON " + json, e);
                System.err.append("Error parsing JSON " + json+ " " +e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't send echo.", e);
                     System.err.append("Couldn't send echo."+e);
            }
        }
    }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue on your server.  I think GCM is intended more as a wakeup tool even though the docs say that a chat program could consume the 4k message.  Once the app is awake you could increase throughput by eliminating the GCM layer and directly connect to the chat server / other device/ pc.

Comment: Are you handling incoming packets similarly to [this](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#smack) piece of code? Check its `addPacketListener()` implementation.

Comment: thanx all - @Koh may you explain more - I will Add My  addPacketListener() implementation